# VS 2010 setup project, Properties | Prerequisites doesn't show VC++ Runtime x64 libs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, visual-c++-2010, prerequisites

Visual Studio 2010 Professional,
target framework/platform: .Net 4/x64

I built a setup project for my application, and when opening its Properties and then Prerequisites, I do not see "Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x64)" listed. The x86 version *is* listed in Prerequisites, however. Both the vcredist_x86 and vcredist_x64 directories have been confirmed as existing in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages
```

I have confirmed this on two different development machines, and with different solutions having setup projects.

The GenericBootstrapper path for 4.0 in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\4.0
```

has been confirmed as pointing to the correct directory.

When going though the registry entries for the packages in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders
```

I noticed that paths for the x86 redistributable were present

```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x86\
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x86\en\
```

but the paths for the x64 package were *not* present. I added the two x64 paths as String Values to the folders directory (I've successfully done this before when building new packages, in order to have new packages appear in the prerequisites listing), but still no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to fix the problem with the vcredist_x64 package as installed, but did find a workaround.

1) In

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\
```

copy the **vcredist_x64** directory to a new name in the Packages directory (I renamed it "custom_vcredist_x64").

2) In RegEdit, go to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders
```

3) In Folders, delete the path strings for the originally installed package if they are present:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x64\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x64\en\
```

4) Now add the two new paths as String Values to the Folders directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\custom_vcredist_x64\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\custom_vcredist_x64\en\
```

5) After closing the registry editor, "Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x64)" will be available in Prerequisites.